# Linked list insertion not working correctly C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am currently trying to insert into a linked list and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I know I'm almost there just can't seem to pin down this bug. The printing is happening in printList but  I think the logic there is pretty solid.

`

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   using namespace std;


struct listBinTreeNode{
public:
    string chStr;
    int prob = 0;
    listBinTreeNode *next;
    listBinTreeNode *left;
    listBinTreeNode *right;


    listBinTreeNode()
    {
        chStr = "dummy";
        next = nullptr;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;

    }

    listBinTreeNode(string chStr, int prob)
    {
        this->chStr = chStr;
        this->prob = prob;
        next = nullptr;
        left = nullptr;
        right= nullptr;
    }

    listBinTreeNode(string chStr, listBinTreeNode *next, listBinTreeNode* left, listBinTreeNode* right)
    {
        this->chStr = chStr;
        this->next = next;
        this->left = left;
        this->right = right;

    }

  void  printNode(string fileOut)
    {
        ofstream outFile;
        outFile.open(fileOut);
        cout<< "chStr: " <<chStr<< "next's chStr: " << next->chStr << "left's chStr: "<< left->chStr<< "right's chStr: " << right->chStr<< endl;
        outFile<< "chStr: " <<chStr<< "next's chStr: " << next->chStr << "left's chStr: "<< left->chStr<< "right's chStr: " << right->chStr<< "\n";
        outFile.close();
    }
};


class HuffmanLinkedList{
public:
    listBinTreeNode * listHead=nullptr;
    listBinTreeNode * oldListHead=nullptr;
    listBinTreeNode dummy;
    HuffmanLinkedList()
    {   //listBinTreeNode *dummy = new listBinTreeNode();
        listHead = &dummy;
    }
  void  constructHuffmanLList(string fileIn, string fileOut)
    {
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open(fileIn);
        //fstream outFile.open(fileOut);
       // listBinTreeNode *dummy = new listBinTreeNode();
        listHead = &dummy;
        string word;
        int wordProb;
        listBinTreeNode  spot;
        while(inFile >> word >> wordProb)
            {
             spot = findSpot(listHead,wordProb);
            // cout<< "this is spot: "<< spot<<endl;
            // cout << "this is listHead.next: "<< listHead->next;
             listBinTreeNode *newNode = new listBinTreeNode(word, wordProb);
             listInsert(spot, *newNode);
             printList(fileOut, listHead);
            } // while
            inFile.close();
          //  outFile.close();
    }
listBinTreeNode findSpot(listBinTreeNode* head, int prob)
    {
        listBinTreeNode * walker = head;
        while( (walker->next !=nullptr) && (prob > (walker->next->prob) )){
            cout<< "here";
            walker = walker->next;
        }
        //if(walker == head){
       //     return walker->next;
      //  }
        return *walker;
    }

 void listInsert(listBinTreeNode spot, listBinTreeNode newNode)
     {
        //if(spot.next!=nullptr){
            newNode.next = spot.next;
            spot.next = &newNode;
        //}
        //spot.next = newNode;
        cout<< spot.next->chStr<< endl;
     }
 void printList(string file, listBinTreeNode* head)
   {
            ofstream outFile;
            outFile.open(file);
            listBinTreeNode* walker = head;
            while(walker->next!=nullptr){
                if(walker == head){
                    cout<<"listHead -->";
                    outFile<<"listHead -->";
                }
                if(walker->next!=nullptr){
                cout << "("<< walker->chStr << ","<<walker->prob << ","<< walker->next->chStr<<") -->";
                outFile << "("<< walker->chStr << ","<<walker->prob << ","<< walker->next->chStr<<") -->";
                walker = walker->next;
                }
            }
            cout << "(" << walker->chStr<<", NULL)"<<endl;
            outFile <<"(" << walker->chStr<<", NULL)--> NULL"<<"\n";

   }
//   outFile.close();
};
```

main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HuffmanLinkedList linkedList;
    HuffmanBinaryTree binTree;
    linkedList.constructHuffmanLList(argv[1], argv[4]);
  //  binTree.constructHuffmanBinTree(linkedList, argv[6]);
 //   string code = binTree.holder.code;
 //   binTree.constructCharCode(binTree.root,code, argv[2]);
 //   binTree.preOrderTraversal(binTree.root,argv[3]);
 //   binTree.inOrderTraversal(binTree.root,argv[4]);
 //   binTree.postOrderTraversal(binTree.root,argv[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

argv[1]:

```
d   2
f   4 
h  15
k  6 
m  47
p  25
w  1
```

my output is :

```
d
(dummy, NULL)
f
(dummy, NULL)
h
(dummy, NULL)
k
(dummy, NULL)
m
(dummy, NULL)
p
(dummy, NULL)
w
(dummy, NULL)
```

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.032 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: Missing a few headers and a `main` function. Worth adding to help people reproduce your error and help you fix it. Doesn't look like you are far from a [mcve] if you write up a tight `main`.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger allows you to single step through your code *watching* the values of variables.  Also, draw the list as you debug.

Comment: BTW, if you differ your class member names from parameter names, you won't need to type `this->` all the time.

Comment: Emphasis on the drawing. Any time you have a pointer-listy structure, a pen and paper are your best friends.

Comment: You should initialize your `prob` variable inside the constructor or in an initialization list.

Comment: If you change the type of the parameter in `printNode` to `std::ostream`, you could easily switch between console output and file output without changing the method.

Comment: Made some updates added a main , thank you all BTW

Comment: Your function is currently creating copies of your arguments and thus the changes aren't being reflected in the passed arguments. The solution is to have your parameters take references: `void listInsert(listBinTreeNode& spot, listBinTreeNode& newNode)`

Comment: 0x499602D2 Hey, I also thought that was this issue, even with that addition there is no change to the output, I'm also not too sure why that is.

Comment: What does the input file (`argv[1]`) contain?

Comment: If this isn't an exercise, just use `std::list`.

Comment: this is an exercise and argv[1] cotains : d   2
f   4 
h  15
k  6 
m  47
p  25
w  1